# display results for loop in one row in r

Tags: r, for-loop

```
intType=function(x) 
{
 for (i in 1:length(x)) if (round(x[i])!=x[i]) {print('Non-integer')} 
                        else if (x[i]%%2 != 0) {print('Odd')} 
                        else {print('Even')}
}

intType(c(1.1, 2, 3))
```

If I run the above code I get:

```
[1] "Non-integer"
[1] "Even"
[1] "Odd"
```

Is there any way to display in one row"? Like this:
"Non-integer" "Even" "Odd"

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ifelse`

```
intType=function(x) 
{
  ifelse(round(x)!=x, 'Non-integer',
                        ifelse(x%%2 != 0, 'Odd', 'Even'))
                        
}
```

-testing

```
> intType(c(1.1, 2, 3))
[1] "Non-integer" "Even"        "Odd"
```

Comment: Thanks. I figure out how to do it in a more rudimentary way.